# Facebook API, sharing photo from public page to user timeline using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, photo, sharing

I would like to ask if there is any Facebook API to share a photo from the public page to the user timeline using javascript. FB.api or FB.ui?
Previously, I can share a feed to the timeline using FB.ui but I cannot find any reference to sharing photos. Hope anyone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To share a photo from a page-

API- `\POST /me/feed`-

Parameter(link to photo)- `link`

To add a photo from a page-

API- `\POST`[`/me/photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/)-

Paramter(link to photo)- `url`